# WCF failing with error "CommunicationObjectFaultedException"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, model-view-controller, wcf-binding

I'm new in using WCF, but i used the same way in other projects but not sure why it keeps gives below error. So the service keeps failing and stop continue with the rest of the code.

> InnerChannel = 'client.InnerChannel' threw an exception of type
> 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException'

the error appears in debug after the first line below

```
SvcSoapClient client = new SvcSoapClient(SvcSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.SvcSoap12);
var temp = await client.getSvcAsync("0" + num, error);
```

Comment: When a faulty communication object is called, a [CommunicationObjectFaultedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.communicationobjectfaultedexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) will be thrown. You can [configure tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing) or handle accurate exceptions in the service and client code,

Comment: that is, [include CommunicationException in the Try Catch block on the client side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/expected-exceptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and then view the exact error.

Comment: what i should be looking for ? i tired to Catch the error but still not sure what to do or how to fix it ? as the WCF working for sometime and sometime not, the message received in the catch is "The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[SvcSoap], cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."

Comment: Client service proxies cannot be reused once they have faulted. You must dispose of the old one and recreate a new one.You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886179/how-to-deal-with-communicationobjectfaultedexception) and the links provided in it.